# Adding a tap Gesture that calls a method in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

Simply I want to add a tap gesture for a `UIImageView` that when the user touches, calls a method that is implemented in another class (not the same class that contains the `UIImageView`).

**Can I do this and if so how can i do it ?**

Comment: `NSNotification` can be one way, another way can be delegation. Use whichever suits you.

Comment: Use touchBegan method and write your code for calling a function any where.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that. But you need the ***instance of the target class*** (class in which method is going to execute) as ***delegate*** or something in the gesture adding class.

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(doSomething)];
```

Here delegate will be the instance of the target class that you have to set before going to that class.

**Edit**

I will explain a little more. Suppose you have two view controller classes VCA and VCB. you want to call a method in VCA from VCB through a tap gesture.

***in VCB.h***

```
@property (nonatomic,assign)VCA *delegate;
```

***in VCB.m***

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(doSomething)];
```

***in VCA.m***

You will present/ push VCB

```
 VCB * viewController = [[VCB alloc]init];
 viewController.delegate = self;
 // push or present viewController
```

Comment: please could you declare more ?!

Answer (score 0):

Declare recognizer selector on init

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = 
[UITapGestureRecognizer 
    initWithTarget:objectOfAnotherClass 
    action:@selector(methodImplementedOnObjectOfAnotherClass:)];
```

- dont forget about defining number of taps  (**[numberOfTapsRequired](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer)**) and optional gesture recognizer required to fail (**[requireGestureRecognizerToFail:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer)**)

[Link to article about selector.](http://iosonlinelessons.blogspot.com/2013/05/few-words-about-selector-sel.html)

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward approach is calling the method of another class from the selector method of `tapGesture` ie.

Add UITapGestureRecogniser to the imageview

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognised)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Dont forget to enable the `userInteraction` of the UIImageView, because by default for imageview userInteraction is disabled.

you can do this like below.

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Then in the selector of tapGestureRecogniser call the method of another class

```
- (void)tapRecognised
{
    [next tappedOnImage];
}
```

Here `next` is the object of another class. You can use delegation also to call the method.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

here self.desired view is the view in which you want to add gesture and you should add gesture in following way

and "webViewTapped.delegate = self" means you want to call a function of the same class when user tap and you can change it to your desired function by using delegate like self.delegate

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *viewTapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
        webViewTapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        webViewTapped.delegate = self;
        [self.desiredView addGestureRecognizer:viewTapped];



- (void)tapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
{
// do your stuff here
}
```