# Adding tap Gesture that calls a function in another class

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to an element. I want that function called after the tap gesture was recognized is in another class.

This is my code :

```
let selectMoment = SelectMomentClass(countUserMoment: 1, cardView: self.cardView)
selectMoment.draw()
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectMoment.selectMomentAction))
cardView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

and my `SelectMomentClass` contains my function:

```
@objc func selectMomentAction(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("card selectMoment is Tapped")
}
```

But when I run the code I have this error:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

Where does my code go wrong? This is the target parameter that I need to change. Can I called a function in another class?

---

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814895/) in Objective-C but it does not help me.

Comment: I almost spoke abut *responder chains* and documentation about *gesture recognizers* not being part of the "normal" chain, but then I clicked on the link you posted and see you haven't post anything related to this part of the answer. (It may not help you, but will help us to help you.) *"But you need the instance of the target class (class in which method is going to execute) as delegate or something in the gesture adding class."* Is `SelectMomentClass` a delegate of the class that has the tap recognizer? If so, look into the responder chain - what you can do for `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: @dfd Thanks for the comment, I resolved my problem to declare my `SelectMomentClass` like a instance variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the object is a local variable it's deallocated after functions ends so make it an instance variable inside its class

```
let selectMoment = SelectMomentClass(countUserMoment: 1, cardView: self.cardView)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this fix the error message but dont give the message "card selectMoment is Tapped" so I think the function was again not called

Comment: you have 2 objcets **selectMoment** and **selectPicture** which one do you want ??

Comment: Yes I edit the post I have only one object selectMoment

Comment: **cardView** is UIView or UIImageView ??

Comment: UIView so `isUserInteractionEnabled` is set to true and the error would not be appear if the card have a problem of subview or other..

Comment: @El-Burritos make the object **let selectMoment = SelectMomentClass(countUserMoment: 1, cardView: self.cardView)** instance variable

Comment: Ok this work, I need to rebuild my class but this work like this thanks ! But delete the down vote please !

Answer (score 1):

Use this.Your method is defined in `selectMomentClass` class then you must add target
as `selectMomentClass` object and selecter as `#selector(selectMoment.SelectPictureAction)`.

```
let selectMoment = SelectMomentClass(countUserMoment: 1, cardView: self.cardView)
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: selectMoment, action: #selector(selectMoment.SelectPictureAction(_:)))
```

**Method Signature as below** in the selectMomentClass.

```
@objc func selectPictureAction(_ sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("card selectMoment is Tapped")
}
```

Comment: thanks, but same issue... this is strange, I don't have any log

Comment: in which class you are creating this SelectMomentClass object ?

Comment: in `class CardCell : UITableViewCell`

Comment: where you get self.cardView ? where you allocates this.

Comment: The problem is solved, I move my let selectMoment to an instance variable and this work well ! can you remove the down vote ?